# Can I use MassTransit (ver. 6.3.2, .NET 4.8) with SQS to consume messages and delete them afterwards?

Tags: .net, windows-services, amazon-sqs, masstransit

In the past I was using MassTransit with RabbitMQ.
Recently, I needed to implement infrastructure handling Amazon Simple Queue Service (sending and consuming messages). MassTransit was chosen instead of native tools in case the queue provider would change in the future. However, I have been struggling a bit with configuration (there is not much documentation, especially for MassTransit ver < 7 and SQS).

I am wondering, is it even possible to configure MassTransit, that after consuming the message it would be deleted from the queue? The only configuration I have seen related with IAmazonSqsBusFactoryConfigurator was AutoDelete, but from what I have found it is related with deleting the whole queue.

My goal is to implement a windows service that would listen to the queue, consume any new messages and after successfully doing that, delete the message from the queue.

I will be grateful for any advice. At this point it may implicate, that MassTransit was probably not the best option. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MassTransit, by default, removes each message from the queue once it has been consumed. This applies to all supported queue-based transports. There is no need to change any of the default receive endpoint settings, such as `AutoDelete`, when configuring the receive endpoint.

If you are not seeing messages removed from the queue once consumed, you likely have a permission issue. I'd suggest looking at the log files, since it's likely your consumer is throwing an exception (and the *_error* queue cannot be created), or you don't have a consumer configured for the message type in the queue (and the *_skipped* queue cannot be created).

Also, [the documentation for v6](https://masstransit-v6.netlify.app/) was archived.